# How do I properly consume this event when a key is pressed that's NOT a number?

Tags: java, validation, javafx

I have been working on a small application for my business, but I am self-taught using YouTube and Google. I am trying to consume the numberValidationEvent when a non-number is pressed, to only allow numbers to be pressed (Phone Number).

Instead, it's always reading as a non-number. Can I get help? I want the event to ignore anything that's not a number (0-9)

```
 private boolean isNumber;
 private String callbackNumber;

 @Override
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    /*
    SOME CODE
    */

    // CALLBACK NUMBER
    Label lblCallbackNumber = new Label("Callback Number:");
    GridPane.setConstraints(lblCallbackNumber, 0, 1);
    TextField txtfCallbackNumber = new TextField();
    txtfCallbackNumber.setPromptText("1234567890");
    GridPane.setConstraints(txtfCallbackNumber, 1, 1);
    txtfCallbackNumber.setOnKeyTyped(numberValidationEvent -> {
        isLong(txtfCallbackNumber, txtfCallbackNumber.getText());
        if(!isNumber) {
            numberValidationEvent.consume();
        }
    });

    /*
    SOME CODE
    */

 }

 private boolean isLong(TextField input, String message){
    try {
        long callbackNumberLong = Long.parseLong(message);
        isNumber = true;
        System.out.println("That was a number!");
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("That was NOT a number!");
        isNumber = false;
        return false;
    }

 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I want the event to ignore anything that's not a number (0-9)_ ? Does it mean that it should result in allowing only numbers in the `TextField` ?

Comment: Why are you passing "TextField input"? You are not using it in your isLong method?

Comment: You can try to trim txtfCallbackNumber.getText() and then pass it to  Long.parseLong. I ran your code on my machine for various inputs and it seems to work fine!

Comment: @Antot I am trying to create a "NumberField" where when a user presses a key, it will ignore any letters, and only accept number (This is a phone number field)

Comment: Though use key event works, but the JavaFX API does provide such filtering functionality. Take a look at [TextInputControl.setTextFormatter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setTextFormatter-javafx.scene.control.TextFormatter-) and [TextFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).

Comment: don't forget to _read_ tutorials, f.i. the introductory ui tutorial referenced in the tag info (those youtubes seem to spread worst practices - you never-ever do any input validation in a keyHandler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest checking the value of the text differently. It is not really ideal to base your outcome on exceptions being thrown.

Also, in the future it is helpful to include all the code doing the work.

---

I suggest checking if the String `message` only contains numbers. I am not sure why you are converting it to a `Long` to check that. Assuming you are using that long when you run `consume()` I will keep it in my example.

Additionally, you are not using a TextField object in `isLong`, you should remove that.

Finally, you are being redundant by returning a boolean that you are not using and just set a boolean within the method. Lets clean that up.

Code to replace `isLong(TextField tf, String m)` is below

```
private boolean isLong(String message){
    if (message.matches("[0-9]+")) {
        try {
            long callbackNumberLong = Long.parseLong(message);
            System.out.println("That was a number!");
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("That was NOT a number!");
            return false;
        } 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you do not need callBackNumberLong as a Long, I suggest not parsing it and keeping it as a string. I have a feeling you wont be doing math with a phone number.

All that is left to do is call `isLong(message)` where you were checking if `isNumber` was true instead of calling `isLong(tf, m)` then checking the boolean value after.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry about the messy code, I only started learning programming this week, and most of my code is from youtube videos, so I didn't realize all of my mistakes. This was a great answer.

1. I did not know how to reference the message from isLong, so thanks! That's why I made a boolean to store outside
2. I didn't know you could do .matches("[0-9]+")

If you google how to make a NumberField in JavaFX, not a lot of simple answers come up.... THANKS!

Comment: Its a great start. Keep at it.
That reference is a regex value I believe (Trying to remember what it is called). They are very helpful for checking the contents on a string. There are other variations you can use for other problems too. Enjoy!

Comment: Also, I ended up having to add a length check, because it was returning false immediately when the textfield was empty, and would not continue, which is why i was getting so confused. Thanks again!

Comment: code is fine, but you might consider to mention using it in a TextFormatter is the way to go :)